# Juju add-machine error - provisioner-harvest-mode is set to destroyed

Tags: 18.04, juju

I am trying to add a remote machine to a particular model in my controller.

- SSH key authentication works as expected.
- Both machines [controller and remote node] can ping each other.
- Both machines are running on Ubuntu 18.04.

However when trying to add remote machine:

```
juju add-machine ssh:test1@192.168.5.5,
```

From `debug-log`

```
controller-0: 11:08:47 INFO juju.worker.provisioner provisioner-harvest-mode is set to destroyed; unknown instances not stopped []
controller-0: 11:09:14 INFO juju.worker.provisioner machine 0 already started as instance “manual:192.168.5.5”
```

When trying to execute

```
juju ssh 0
```

I get

```
ERROR retrieving SSH host keys for “0”: keys not found
```

I can’t seem to understand what the issue is about.
Can someone kindly help me on this?

Comment: The 4 th homework question of the day?

Comment: @David - I can't seem to find a way around this, I'm actually stuck.

Comment: I changed the config of provisioner-harvest-mode to none, however controller is still seein the node as unknown

Comment: @David - When adding machines part of the lxd where the controller is initiated works successfully, however the issue is when I'm trying to add machines outside of the lxd controller